# Why is i++ looping twice here?

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

When below code executes i=0, j=0 and length = 9 and loops = 3

Surprisingly with each line, i increased by 2 rather than 1.

Can you tell why?

```
        String arr[] = stringToSplit.split(delimiter);
        int length = arr.length;
        int loops = length/4+length%4;
        for(int i=0,j=0; j<loops && i<length; j++){
            DummyClass dummyClass= new DummyClass ();
            MyHelper.addInMappedElement(i<length?arr[i++]:null, value1, dummyClass) ;
            MyHelper.addInMappedElement(i<length?arr[i++]:null, value2, dummyClass) ;
            MyHelper.addInMappedElement(i<length?arr[i++]:null, value3, dummyClass) ;
            MyHelper.addInMappedElement(i<length?arr[i++]:null, value4, dummyClass) ;
        }
```

Note: I am aware that i should be incrementing 4 times after completing one loop but that is not the case here. For eg : if the array is [Value1 ,  value2 ,  value 3 ,  value 4, Value5 ,  value12 ,  value q3 ,  value w4,  val5]

What I get mapped in my final result is just value 3 ,Value5, value q3 and val5.

Do you get my question now?

Comment: Ewww; why don't you just `break` if `i >= length` instead of having `.addInMappedElement()` handle null?

Comment: you mean that after 2 iteration the loops stops, j=2 and i=10 ?

Comment: I have written it myself! :|

Comment: @fge  How many times do I do that? i >= length; after each line? I dont think that looks great!

Comment: What does `MyHelper.addInMappedElement` do?

Comment: It has this signature public static addInMappedElement(Object object, Integer childId, MappedDistributionDataElements DummyClass )  It just takes the value of object and prints it. I get array object values here not even int i

Comment: @dish Can you show the code of that method? If it just prints the object, what are the other arguments passed to it for?

Comment: First, please add any additional information as an edit to your question, not as a comment. Comments are not good for code formatting. And if you have its code, you better add that as well. Your description is very vague. If it's not yours, a link to the javadoc would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the fix :

```
 for(int i=0,j=0; j<loops && i<length; j++){
        DummyClass dummyClass= new DummyClass ();
        MyHelper.addInMappedElement(i<length?arr[i++].toString():null, value1, dummyClass) ;
        MyHelper.addInMappedElement(i<length?arr[i++].toString():null, value2, dummyClass) ;
        MyHelper.addInMappedElement(i<length?arr[i++].toString():null, value3, dummyClass) ;
        MyHelper.addInMappedElement(i<length?arr[i++].toString():null, value4, dummyClass) ;
    }
```

B-)

Answer (score 3):

You have 4 `i++` statements in each iteration, so it's actually incremented up to 4 times (as long as `i<length`).

Comment: Depending on the original value of length, which I'm guessing is 2

Comment: I am aware that i should be incrementing 4 times after completing one loop but that is not the case here. For eg : if the array is [Value1 , value2 , value 3 , value 4, Value5 , value12 , value q3 , value w4, val5]

What I get mapped in my final result is just value 3 ,Value5, value q3 and val5.

Do you get my question now?

Answer (score 1):

`i++` is the same as:

```
int temp = i;
i = i + 1;   ← i is actually changed ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
return temp;
```

`i` is incremented 4 times in your code.